# Any Addin for Visual Studio 2008 which would sort the imports?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, plugins, add-in, visual-studio-addins

I have seen plugins for VS 2005 and also for C# environment in VS2008 but not able to find for VB.NET environment in VS 2008.I want it to sort for each file, is there any addin for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe RefactorPro ($99) supports this on a per file basis. http://devexpress.com/refactor.

The functionality is called "Optimise Namespace References"

The current versions of [CodeRush](http://devexpress.com/coderush), [RefactorPro](http://devexpress.com/refactor) and [CodeRush Xpress](http://devexpress.com/crx) support VB.Net and C# under VS2005, VS2008 and VS2010*/**

Feel free to ask me any Refactor / CodeRush (Xpress or Pro) questions, either http://twitter.com/rorybecker or rorybecker@gmail.com

Notes: 
*VS2010 support is already available for CodeRush Xpress. RefactorPro and CodeRush support is at release candidate stage and is expected any time now.
** CodeRush and RefactorPro also have an earlier version that supports VS2002 and VS2003